# How to publish a WAMP Server project with one click?

Tags: wordpress, wamp

I'm making lots of WordPress sites and currently editing files directly on cpanel accounts via FTP. I would like to do this a different way and I wonder if it is possible:

1. Develop in WAMP on my local machine (I have this set up)
2. One click publishing and/or updating of the project to a cpanel account (files and database).
3. Synch the live cpanel site back to the WAMP environment to do ongoing work and testing (files and database).

I am NOT looking for instructions to manually move WP to a server. These are all over the place and I know how. I want to work from my local machine and synch/publish to the server with a single click, or at least something very simple.

Thank you in advance

Comment: [Duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) is great for quick deployments. [WP Migrate DB Pro](https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-migrate-db-pro/) is great for keeping databases in sync.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use WP Migrate DB Pro for managing database and media copies from one server to another. I use beanstalk with auto-deployment for pushing code to my ftp servers (I have at least one test site and a single live site for every website I work on)